# My first maven example fails (using m2eclipse) : 'mainClass' missing

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, configuration, m2eclipse

I am trying to get work this [Maven by Example](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/customizing-sect-custom-exec.html), using Eclipse + m2Eclipse plugin. However, I got this error

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) on project simple-weather: The parameters 'mainClass' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java are missing or invalid

But I did specify mainClass in this way (screenshot below) with mainClass specified in the Profiles lines. Any idea why I still got wrong? Many thanks.

[image]

Comment: Do you execute the `mvn install` before? It is a required step before executing the `mvn exec:java`.

Comment: Have you tried the examples on command line outside from Eclipse? Which Eclipse version do you use? Have you an up-to-date installation of m2e ? Does a complete build on command line work `mvn clean package`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says, you are missing the parameter `mainClass`.

You have put the parameters in the `Profiles` part which is the wrong place.

Press the `Add...` button and add the parameter and value in the box like this:

[image]

It should look like this when you press `Ok`:

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot for this quick and detailed answer. Very helpful!

Comment: @zell I'm glad I could help although I'm not an eclpise user myself.